# Inserting python variable into SQlite Database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have seen some posts that suggesting using a ? as a place holder when inserting python variables into a SQL Query but all of these examples show the question mark at the end of the query followed by the python variable. What if you want to insert a python variable in the middle of a query and want to avoid SQL injection? I am using Python 3.6 and SQLite.

Update* - This code is working:
    id='13'
    text='YES'

```
db=sqlite3.connect('NEW_Inventory.sqlite')
cursor=db.cursor()
query=('''      
INSERT 
    OR REPLACE
INTO
    text (id, text)  
VALUES
    (?,
        (SELECT
           CASE 
              WHEN exists(SELECT 1  FROM text WHERE id=?)
              THEN 'good' 
              ELSE 'Hello' 
           END
         )
    )''')

cursor.execute(query, (id, id))
db.commit()
```

Comment: When I run your code, I receive a different error message: `TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`. Which is expected since you would have to give the query arguments as a list.

Comment: where is mysql here, you tag mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters to `execute()` as a *tuple*. In your case you need to call it like this:

```
cursor.execute(query, (id, id))
```

where `query` is your parameterised SQL query string.

I assume that your code defines `id` somewhere, otherwise, `execute()` will try to use the builtin function `id()` to construct the query, resulting in another error.

It also worth mentioning that if you have only one parameter it must also be passed as a tuple like this `(id,)`. Avoid the common mistake of this: `(id)` which is not a tuple.

Comment: An other mistake, but not the one responsible for the error message.

Comment: @KlausD. OP reports a different message than that which is actually generated by the code posted, as you commented, incorrect number of arguments. This actual error message _is_ due to the reason explained in this answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have updated my code in response to your answer. My code is now running without error but data is not being input to the sqlite database

Comment: @Tim: you've removed the `db.commit()`, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes it is... Thanks so much for your help